# Java throws keyword not working

Tags: java, exception

I have an issue with throws keyword in Exception Handling Java.. Here is the code. I expect the Code to print `"Improper Input to parse method!"` and `"Divide by 0 error!"`. But I am only getting `"Divide by 0 error!"`.

```
class D {
    void add() throws ArithmeticException,NumberFormatException {
        int a = 9;
        System.out.println(a / 0); 
        Xyz.test();
    }
}

class Xyz {
    public static void test() throws NumberFormatException {
        int a = Integer.parseInt("bc");
    }
}

class Abc {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try{
            D d = new D();
            d.add();
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Improper Input to parse method!");
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException ex) {
            System.out.println("Divide by 0 Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one  `catch` block can be triggered by a given `Exception`, it isn't cumulative.

Comment: `a / 0` will throw the ArithmeticException so `test()` won't be called at all and hence you r code never throws the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: "*Java throws keyword not working*" - Please keep in mind that Java turns 22 tomorrow (or today, depending on where you live). It is highly unlikely that a keyword like `throws` does malfunction.

Answer (score 1):

This is working exactly as expected. `System.out.println(a / 0);` throws an [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/?java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) because you cannot divide by 0. This is then caught in your `main` method by the second catch block, after which your program terminates. Execution does *not* continue normally after an exception has been handled.

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/index.html) chapter [11.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) says:

> When an exception is thrown ([§14.18](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.18)), control is transferred from the code that caused the exception to the nearest dynamically enclosing `catch` clause, if any, of a `try` statement ([§14.20](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20)) that can handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't return to its normal work (in your code to calling `Xyz.test();`) after throwing first `Exception` it meets, so it doesn't have a possibility to continue performing rest of `add()` method.